# Sources about learning to defend oneself

Tags: sources-mekorot, health-safety-shmira

Does the Torah require one to know how to defend one's self if attacked?

Comment: "Haba Lehargecha Hashkem Lehargo"?

Comment: There are probably implications in the last siman of Choshen Mishpat that could help with this.